# CodeIgniter and Google map api lat long error

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter, google-maps

My code was working perfectly fine but suddenly it stopped working and I am getting this error .

I am using below code for Lat long:

```
$geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $prepAddr . '&sensor=false');
$output = json_decode($geocode);
$data['latitude'] = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$data['longitude'] = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

while using the url (http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=')in browser I am not able to get the lat long .

Below query  I am using in the code

```
$qry = "SELECT  * , ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(  " . $lat . " ) ) * COS( RADIANS(  `latitude` ) ) * COS( RADIANS(  `longitude` ) - RADIANS(  " . $lon . " ) ) + SIN( RADIANS(  " . $lat . " ) ) * SIN( RADIANS(  `latitude` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM  `property` WHERE STATUS = 1 HAVING distance < " . RADIUS;
```

Below is the error that I am facing .

> Error Number: 1582
>
> Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'RADIANS'
>
> SELECT * , ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( ) ) * COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS( ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM `property` WHERE STATUS = 1 HAVING distance < 50

Most weird part is that this code is working fine in my local but in my live website it is throwing this error.

Comment: Function [radians()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_radians) expects argument (I.E. RADIANS(90)), so $lat `is_empty()`.

Comment: That code will never have worked if you did not supply a parameter to the `RADIANS( )` function.